# Bootstrap datatable search function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, bootstrap-table

I want to searching multicolumn value on the bootstrap table. There is any code for this

For example ;

> https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

I want to searching like this but I could not find anything. I can post the data input on the server and write SQL query about LİKE . But it does not specific . Do have any example about it ?

Have a good day :)

**My page screenshot**
[image]

**My table source code**

```
<div class="table-responsive " style="height: 400px; overflow-y: auto;">
              <table id="tablo_icin2" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">

                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>
                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-sm checkbox-toggle"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i></span>
                  </th>
                  <th>User Name</th>
                  <th>Password</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tr>
                <td></th>
                <td>Mark</th>
                <td>123</th>
                </tr>

              </table>
             </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of bootgrid as plugin for bootstrap.

[image]
http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Examples

Comment: There is .Click on start example. Below you will find tabs of code for HTML and JS.